# How to select rows from a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, mat

I am a beginner in matlab. Currently I am saving a file using,

```
eval(['save(''results/loc_', num2str(location) ,''',''values'')']);
```

I have 54 locations. So in this case I will save 54 files named as loc_1,loc_2...loc_54 in a new folder named as 'results'. The size of each file is 15x7. In this case the number of columns will always remain the same. But the number of rows will change. If I take only one trial,then 'loc_1' will give only 3x7 values. If I take 2 trials, then 'loc_1' will give 6x7 values and so on. In my case I want to take 'trial' as a variable and its value is 5. So each file named as loc_1,loc_2,..,loc_54 will give me 15x7 values.

Now I want to separate first 5 rows (and all 7 columns) from loc_1 and need to save them in 3 different files and the size of each file will be 5x7. Similarly I will have to save all the loc_numstr(location) files (that is a total of 54 files) and separate them like this. Then I will have 3 sets of 54 files of each size as 5x7. In this case I am taking 5 trials, so I am separating as 5x7 as the size of each file. Similarly for 4 trials, I need to consider 4x7 and so on.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I think I made it a bit complicated. Can you explain me this example please?

I want to ask if I have a matrix for example : 
         a=[1 2 3 ; 1 3 4 ; 4 5 7 ; 9 10 12 ; 13 16 18 ; 22 26 29]

and how to take first 2 rows and save them in another file, then the next 2 rows and save them in another file and the next 2 rows and save them in another file?

For example, I want to store b= [1 2 3 ; 1 3 4 ] , c= [4 5 7 ; 9 10 12 ] and d= [13 16 18 ; 22 26 29]

thanks

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Why not just `save(['results/loc_', num2str(location)], values)`? Also your question is extremely difficult to understand. What is `values`?

Comment: I honestly can't at all follow what you're trying to do. To answer the explicit question, see MATLAB's [matrix indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) documentation. There is also no need to use `eval` here. Use [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) or [`strcat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html) to generate your filename.

Comment: I was trying to use save but it was difficult for me to use that. Yes I think I made it a bit complicated. Can you explain me this example please? I am giving an example by making an edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you can just use array slicing,

```
a=[1 2 3 ; 1 3 4 ; 4 5 7 ; 9 10 12 ; 13 16 18 ; 22 26 29]
for n = 1:3
   %Indices for matrix section
   j = 2*n; i = j-1;
   %Get matrix section to save
   b = a(i:j,:)
   save(['results/loc_',num2str(n)], 'b')
end
```

I'm not sure save is what you want -- this saves the matlab workspace variables. Did you want to write the numbers so they can be read by other program?

Comment: Please ignore 'save'. I am using many files to generate a final result. Then I am using the eval function to save the result. I have 54 results now. The files are named as loc_1,loc_2,..loc_54. And the size of each file is 15x7. I want to separate the rows from the result file. For example, loc_1 has a size of 15x7. Now I want to save the first 5 rows (a 5x7 matrix) in loc_test1_1, then the next 5 rows as (another 5x7 matrix) loc_test2_1 and then the next 5 rows (another 5x7 matrix) as loc_test3_1. So like this we will have 3 new sets from loc_1 file. Here we have 54 files from loc_1 to loc_54

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saving values to files and (I assume) reloading between operations. Typically writing to disk is very inefficient and should only be done to save values you need between matlab sessions. If I understand what you want to do next, this will use exactly the same approach as above but with different filenames and indices...